# where do include all additional unmanaged dependency dll in windows phone app

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-phone-8.1, unmanaged

i want to import some C++ unmanaged dlls into my windows phone app. can i do this ?? while debugging the dll not found exception thrown. can anyone help me to where do i place my those dependency dlls .

thank you ...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the DLL. If the DLL is built using only API available to Windows Runtime apps then you can use it. See [Win32 and COM for Windows Runtime apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx) on MSDN for a list of the available API. You won't be able to use a DLL built for a desktop system (you cannot run x86 or x64 on ARM) but will need a specific phone build.

To use it you will need to include it in your appx package. In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer add the DLL to your project and edit its properties to mark its Build Action as Content. When you build the app check to make sure it is in the appx directory. That will deploy the DLL with the app so it is available at runtime.

Comment: hey rob... i built dlls in VS2008, i want to use the same dll in windows phone app too. for that i used dllimport attribute, directly on C#. now i want to know where to place those dlls. while debugging VS2013 throw dll not found exception. it causes two reason 1).might not place the dll where it currently searches 2).may not be in usable format

Comment: You can't use an x86/x64 DLL built in VS2008 on Windows Phone. You'll need to recompile it for Windows Phone.

Comment: yeah....rob actually i place the C++ built under v2013 in system32 folder....now the windows phone app takes my dll and run too..if it is phone where do i place those dlls. please help me...

Comment: You have to include the DLLs in the appx package so they are installed with the app.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to having WIC code in my App and/or calling CoCreateInstance in a windows phone environment ( on PC it works flawlessly though )